# Nonhomogeneous Semi-Linear PDE with the Characteristic Method

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I need to solve this semi-linear PDE:

$u_x - 3u_y = \sin (y) + \cos  (x)$

The initial condition provided is:

$ u (t,t)= t^2$

I need to use the **Characteristic Method**. I learned the method from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LpHqrlrU5pM&t=0s&list=PLGCj8f6sgswntUil8yzohR_qazOfYZCg_&index=13).

I have reached an answer. However, I am not sure if it is wright. I am insecure in two different moments of my solution.

My intermediate steps are:

First constant: $c_1= y + 3x $

Second constant: $c_2= x\cos y -\cos x-u$

The second constant above is my **first source of insecurity**.

I needed to solve this equality as an ODE:

$\frac{dx}{1}= \frac{du}{\sin x + \cos y}$

I did so with this approach:

$\int (\sin x + \cos y) dx = \int 1 du $

Using integral properties:
$(\int \sin x dx) + (\int \cos y dx) = \int 1 du $

Which results in:
$c_2= x\cos y -\cos x-u$

I am not sure if this is right. I don't know why, but I am affraid I can't treat \cos y as a constant on the second integral.

Supposing this was correct, I tried to go on. So I used an arbitrary function G to make the relation between both constants. Hence,   $c_2 =G(c_1) $ and we have that:

$ x\cos y -\cos x-u  = G(y + 3x) $

With the initial condition we have:

$G(4x) = x\cos y -\cos x- x^2$

This result above is my **second source** of insecurity.

Before, I was dealing with clear arbitraty functions like $G(x)$ or $G(y)$.
Now, the result is different. I did some manipulation to put it on the more casual form. So:

$G(x) = \frac{x}{4}\cos y -\cos\frac{x}{4}- \frac{x^2}{16}$

After the definition of $G(x)$ above , I *inputed* the value of $c_1$ , having:

$G(y + 3x) = \frac{y+3x}{4}\cos y -\cos\frac{y+3x}{4} - \frac{(y+3x)^2}{16} $.

Finally, solving for $u$:

$u(x,y) =  -\frac{y+3x}{4}\cos y +\cos\frac{y+3x}{4} + \frac{(y+3x)^2}{16} + x\cos y -\cos x $

Is this right?

If I did something wrong, what was it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$u_x - 3u_y = \sin (y) + \cos  (x),\qquad (1)\\
u(t,t)=t^2 \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\ (2)$$
Solution of  $u_x - 3u_y =0$ is
$$u_h=G(y+3x).$$ 
Particular solution of $(1)$ is
$$u_p=\sin{(x)}+\frac{\cos{(y)}}{3}.$$
Then general solution of $(1)$ is
$$u=u_h+u_p=G(y+3x)+\sin{(x)}+\frac{\cos{(y)}}{3}.$$
From $(2)$ we get
$$G(4t) +\sin{(t)}+\frac{\cos{(t)}}{3}={{t}^{2}}.$$
Then 
$$G(t)=\frac{t^2}{16}-\sin\left(\frac{t}{4}\right)-\frac{\cos{(\frac{t}{4})}}{3}.$$

Solution of problem $(1), (2)$ is
$$u=\frac{{{\left( y+3 x\right) }^{2}}}{16}-\sin{\left( \frac{y+3 x}{4}\right) }-\frac{\cos{\left( \frac{y+3 x}{4}\right) }}{3}+\sin{(x)}+\frac{\cos{(y)}}{3}$$

Comment: I think you have the particular and homogeneous solutions mixed up

Comment: @Dylan Thank you, I corrected it.

Comment: Thanks @AleksasDomarkas, Great explanation. But I have one doubt. What is the formula for the particular solution?    I don't know this one.